# SwiftUI: Alert dismissing itself automatically (when it shouldn't!)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I am writing a SwiftUI app using the MVVM pattern.  I'm running into a situation where I am presenting an app setup screen and prompting the user for a password.  To perform password validation, I have a series of Combine `Publisher`s in my `ViewModel` that validate against numerous criteria.  If the password validates successfully, a "Complete Registration" button is enabled in my `View`, and upon tapping it the account is established.  If an error occurs while creating the account, an `Alert` is supposed to be displayed.  However, I am finding in my testing that when the alert is displayed it immediately dismisses itself.  Here's what my `ViewModel` looks like:

```
struct ApplicationSetupState {
    
}

enum ApplicationSetupInput {
    case completeSetup
}

class ApplicationSetupViewModel: ViewModel {
    
    typealias ViewModelState = ApplicationSetupState
    typealias ViewModelInput = ApplicationSetupInput
    
    enum PasswordValidation {
        case valid
        case empty
        case noMatch
    }
    
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var confirmPassword: String = ""
    @Published var useBiometrics: Bool = false
    
    @Published var isValid: Bool = false
    
    @Published var state: ApplicationSetupState
    @Published var errorMessage: String? = nil
    @Published var error: Bool = false
    
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
    
    private var isPasswordEmptyPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        $password
            .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map { password in
                DDLogVerbose("Mapping password=\(password)")
                return password == ""
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var arePasswordsEqualPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Publishers.CombineLatest($password, $confirmPassword)
            .debounce(for: 0.1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .map { password, confirmPassword in
                DDLogVerbose("Mapping password=\(password), confirmPassword=\(confirmPassword)")
                return password == confirmPassword
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var isPasswordValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<PasswordValidation, Never> {
        Publishers.CombineLatest(isPasswordEmptyPublisher, arePasswordsEqualPublisher)
            .map { isPasswordEmpty, arePasswordsEqual in
                DDLogVerbose("Mapping isPasswordEmpty=\(isPasswordEmpty), arePasswordsEqual=\(arePasswordsEqual)")
                if isPasswordEmpty {
                    return .empty
                } else if !arePasswordsEqual {
                    return .noMatch
                }
                
                return .valid
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private var isSetupValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        isPasswordValidPublisher
            .map { isPasswordValid in
                return isPasswordValid == .valid
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    init() {
        self.state = ApplicationSetupState()
        
        self.isPasswordValidPublisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { passwordValidation in
                DDLogVerbose("Mapping passwordValidation=\(passwordValidation)")
                switch passwordValidation {
                case .empty:
                    return "You must provide a master password"
                case .noMatch:
                    return "The passwords do not match.  Try again."
                default:
                    return ""
                }
            }
            .assign(to: \.errorMessage, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        self.isSetupValidPublisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isValid, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func trigger(_ input: ApplicationSetupInput) {
        switch input {
        case .completeSetup:
            self.completeApplicationSetup()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private methods
    
    private func completeApplicationSetup() {
        DDLogInfo("Completing application setup...")
        
        do {
            let status = try ApplicationSetupController.shared.completeApplicationSetup(withPassword: self.password,
                                                                                        useBiometrics: self.useBiometrics)
            DDLogVerbose("status=\(status)")
            if status == true {
                DDLogInfo("Application setup completed successfully.  Posting notification...")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didCompleteSetup, object: nil)
            } else {
                DDLogWarn("Application setup failed with no error message")
                self.error = true
                self.errorMessage = "An unknown error occurred during setup.  Please try again."
            }
        } catch {
            DDLogError("ERROR while completing application setup - \(error)")
            self.error = true
            self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        }
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, I have a `@State` variable called `error` that indicates whether or not there is an error situation.  My `View` looks something like this:

```
struct MasterPasswordSetupView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ApplicationSetupViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            ...stuff...
        }
            .alert(isPresented: self.$viewModel.error) {
                Alert(title: Text("Error"),
                      message: Text(self.viewModel.errorMessage ?? ""),
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")) {
                        DDLogVerbose("OK pressed!")
                      })
            }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the `Alert` is displayed if error is true within my `ViewModel`.  However, I am seeing that as soon as the `Alert` is displayed it is immediately dismissed, even though I have not pressed the OK button to dismiss it.

I've added some logging, including a `didSet` method on `error`, and see that at some point error is, in fact, toggled back to false.  However, I am not explicitly doing this anywhere within my code, so I'm at a loss as to why it is happening.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to create @StateObject instead of @ObservedObject.

```
@StateObjec var viewModel: ApplicationSetupViewModel
```

I think the issue is that your viewModel is reloading.

Comment: That was exactly it!  So, for my own benefit, what is the difference between those two property wrappers?  Does @ObservedObject reset my view model automatically or something?

Comment: ok great. Can you please accept my answer. Your ObservedObject was initialized again. Pleas see the link to find details information 

https://www.donnywals.com/whats-the-difference-between-stateobject-and-observedobject/

Comment: That link also gives you an idea of what the problem with the initial code is. It looks like the viewModel is passed in as part of the initialiser. In which case the original code should work. You are probably seeing this behaviour because at the point you create the view model and pass it to the view, you aren't keeping a strong reference to the view model. Since this View isn't creating the viewModel, it shouldn't need to use `@StateObject`

Comment: I've same problem, even I am using @StateObject, View disappears immediately with alert and .disAppear didn't get call